# How to subtract strings that are not consecutive python

Tags: python-3.7

What I mean is if I have a string, "apwswe", and another string "appegwisbnwe", if we "subtract" the two strings together, which means "appegwisbnwe" - "apwswe", I want to get "pegibn". Is there a way to do this? BTW pegibn is the characters that they don't have in "common" with eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a thing of beauty, but this will get you there:

```
subtrahend = "apwswe"
minuend = list("appegwisbnwe")

for char in subtrahend:
    if minuend.count(char):
        minuend.remove(char)
        
difference = "".join(minuend)
print(difference)
```

```
pgibne
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternatives to rhurwitz's solution:

```py
input = "appegwisbnwe"
for char, occurrences in collections.Counter("apwswe"):
    input = input.replace(char, '', occurrences)
```

this is quite simple and can be implemented as a straightforward `functools.reduce` expression but will rewrite the `input` string as many times as there are different characters in the filter.

A possibly more efficient alternative as it works in `O(len(input) + len(filter))` rather than `O(len(input)*len(uniq(filter))`

```py
input = "appegwisbnwe"
filter = collections.Counter("apwswe")
output = ''
for c in input:
    if filter[c]:
        filter[c] -= 1
    else:
        output += c
```